# Necessary condition of complex numbers zero product

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-verification

$w,z$ are complex numbers. Prove that if $w\cdot z=0$ then $w=0$ or $z=0$

My proof is:

Suppose that there exist $w\neq0$ and $z\neq0$ such that $wz=0$.
Thus $w=\frac0z=0$. Contradiction.

Is this proof correct?
Can you suggest anything better?

Comment: That's fine.  Alternatively, you can do this without contradiction:  If $wz = 0$ and $w \neq 0$, then $z = 0$ by dividing through by $w$.

Comment: I see a problem in the proof as why you are allowed to divide by $z$.  If you claim that it is because $z$ is non-zero, then that works because $\mathbb C$ is a field, which is a greater argument than the problem we are solving.  (And in any field $ab=0$ implies that either $a$ or $b$ is zero.)

Comment: Dear user, This question is hard to answer without knowing exactly what definition of the complex numbers you are using and what facts are already being assumed to be true or have already been proved.  (@CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón's comment is one reflection of this state of affairs.)  Regards,

Answer (score 11):

$wz=0$ **iff** $|wz|=0$ **iff** $|w||z| = 0$ **iff** $|w|=0$ or $|z|=0$.

Comment: that's a nice approach (+1)

Answer (score 4):

In this entire post, I'm assuming you can use the fact that you can divide by non-zero real numbers.

The fact that you can divide by non-zero things actually *depends* on the zero-product principle. I would show that $(a + bi)(c + di) = 0, \ a + bi \ne 0 \implies c + di = 0$.

If $(a + bi)(c + di) = (ac - bd) + (ad + bc)i$ is zero, then $ac = bd$ and $ad + bc = 0$. We know that either $a$, $b$, or both is non-zero.

Case $a \ne 0$: Multiply the former by $c$ and the latter by $d$ to get $ac^2 = bcd$ and $ad^2 + bcd = 0$. Substitute to get $a(c^2 + d^2) = 0$, then divide by $a$.

Case $b \ne 0$: Multiply the former by $d$ and the latter by $c$ to get $acd = bd^2$ and $acd + bc^2 = 0$. Substitute to get $b(c^2 + d^2) = 0$, then divide by $b$.

Either way, $c^2 + d^2 = 0$. Since both are real, $c^2, d^2 \ge 0$. So $c = d = 0$.

EDIT: If you need to prove that $a + bi = 0$ implies $a = b = 0$: Assume $a + bi = 0$ and $b \ne 0$. This gives $-a = bi$, and since $b$ is real and non-zero, $-\frac{a}{b} = i$. But because the left side is real and the right side is not, this is absurd, so $b = 0$. Then we have $a + 0i = 0 \implies a = 0$.

Comment: We know that $a + bi \neq 0$, but that doesn't imply $a$ and $b$ are both nonzero.  There might be some subtleties using this approach.

Comment: Say $a + bi = 0$. Then $-bi = a \in \mathbb{R}$. But it shouldn't be too hard to show that's only true when $b = 0$. (Maybe square, show it's negative, and that can't happen in $\mathbb{R}$?)

Comment: Indeed, $a + bi = 0$ implies $a = b = 0$.  I just had some reservation where you say 'Since $a, b \neq 0$', because we are only assuming $a + bi \neq 0$ (e.g.  $a + bi = 1 + 0i \neq 0$, but $b = 0$ in this case).  I believe this approach is fine, but it might take a case-by-case analysis ($a = 0$ and $b \neq 0$, or $a, b \neq 0$, etc.) if you wanted to be really careful.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I'll patch it up then.

Comment: Nice! (admittedly, I was being a bit pedantic.) (+1)

Answer (score 0):

*Discovering this 6 years too late, but, nonetheless:*

The exercise appears in https://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/ch1.pdf , in the context of constructing the complex numbers as ordered pairs of reals, and defining the complex product as $(x, y)(u, v) = (xu - yv, xv + yu)$.  The proof suggested in the question is incorrect, because we don't yet know those assumptions for *complex* product and division; indeed, that it was we're proving.  Remember, at this point, although the complex product is written similarly to real product, we have no reason to believe they have similar properties.

Rather, the proof is:

$(x, y) * (u, v) = (xu - yv, xv + yu) = (0, 0)$ means $xu = yv$ and $xv = -yu$. If $y$ is zero, either $x$ is zero, which is QED, or $u$ is zero.  If $y$ is zero and $x$ is nonzero, $v$ must also be zero, which again is QED.  If $y$ is nonzero, $u$ must be zero, since otherwise $v = xu/y$, so $x^2u/y = -yu$, and $x^2 = -y^2$, which is impossible since $x$ and $y$ are real.  If $u$ is zero and $y$ nonzero, $v$ must be zero, QED.

Note that the problem could be restated in high school real algebra, "If $xu - yv = 0$ and $xv + yu = 0$, show that $x$ and $y$ are zero or $u$ and $z$ are zero," which is precisely the point: to show that statements about complex numbers are just a convenient shorthand for statements about real numbers.  Also note that the property depends on the fact that $x$, $y$, $u$, and $v$ are real.  If we would try to define a "super-complex" number $(x, y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are complex, we'd have nonzero $w$ and $z$ but $wz = 0$, e.g. $(i,1)$ and $(1,i)$.